# Convert name value pairs stored as rows to columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have a table as follows:

```
ID  | FieldName     | FieldValue
--------------------------------
01  | event_name    | Event Title
01  | event_cost    | 10.00
01  | event_loc     | Leeds
02  | event_name    | Another Event
02  | event_cost    | 15.00
02  | event_loc     | London
```

I want to query this and return results as follows:

```
Title           | Cost  | Location
------------------------------------
Event Title     | 10.00 | Leeds
Another Event   | 15.00 | London
```

What would be the best way to do this? I have tried using a SELECT query, but I can only return one field value, and I cannot seem to join them.

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use case expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use case when

```
select id, max( case when FieldName='event_name' then FieldValue end) as Title,
max(case when FieldName='event_cost' then FieldValue end) as cost,
max(case when FieldName='event_loc' then FieldValue end) as Location from t
group by id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=940326493ef7b561375953f85f65a4ea

```
id  Title   cost    Location
1   Event Title     10.0    Leeds
2   Another Event   15.0    London
```

Comment: Trusting MySQL auto sorting on `GROUP BY` has been deprecated since MySQL version 5.7 .. MySQL 8.0+ requires a `ORDER BY` to sort `GROUP BY`

Comment: I have tried this query, and it returns the results in the form I need, but it is only returning the last result - Is there a way to return all?

Comment: @PaulJames it will return all

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin It is only returning one result for me

Comment: @PaulJames https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=940326493ef7b561375953f85f65a4ea check  link it retuns all

Comment: @PaulJames have  you checked fiddle  link i create for you sample https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=940326493ef7b561375953f85f65a4ea

Answer (score 3):

You can do *conditional* aggregation :

```
select max(case when FieldName = 'event_name' then FieldValue end) as Title,
       max(case when FieldName = 'event_cost ' then FieldValue end) as Cost,
       max(case when FieldName = 'event_loc' then FieldValue end) as Location
from table t
group by id;
```

Comment: Trusting MySQL auto sorting on `GROUP BY` has been deprecated since MySQL version 5.7 .. MySQL 8.0+ requires a `ORDER BY` to sort `GROUP BY`

Comment: I have tried this query, and it returns the results in the form I need, but it is only returning the first result - how would I change it to return all?

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation. `GROUP_CONCAT` could be used to return a comma separated list if there are multiple matches for a specific field name.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'event_name' THEN FieldValue END) AS Title,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'event_cost' THEN FieldValue END) AS Cost,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'event_loc'  THEN FieldValue END) AS Location
FROM yourdata
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: MySQL auto sorting on GROUP BY has been deprecated since MySQL version 5.7 .. MySQL 8.0+ does not auto sort GROUP BY annymore. topicstarter If you want a fixed order always you should use `ORDER BY` also

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT event_name AS 'Title', event_cost AS 'Cost', event_loc AS 'Location' 
FROM yourTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Use case when and aggregation:

```
select max(case when fieldname='event_name' then FieldValue) as title,
max(case when fieldname='event_cost' then FieldValue) as cost,
max(case when fieldname='event_loc' then FieldValue) as location,
from tablename group by id
```

Comment: Trusting MySQL auto sorting on `GROUP BY` has been deprecated since MySQL version 5.7 .. MySQL 8.0+ requires a `ORDER BY` to sort `GROUP BY`

Comment: I have tried this query, and it returns the results in the form I need, but it is only returning the first result - Is there a way to return all?